# Front End Management of Joomla Users

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions, custom-component, user

Joomla 3.9.20

I know there's no default way of managing Joomla **users** on the front end (*a huge drawback of Joomla imo)*. There appears to be some commercial extensions and components that do this, but they are all quite bulky and offer more than what I require.

I'd like to offer the ability to **view** the same information in the image below (name, username, email, last visit date, registration date), and perhaps even toggle the 'Enabled' and 'Activated' status. Pagination of the user list is also required.

[image]

I'm surprised this isn't a default module in Joomla at this stage. The functionality exists on the back end, i'm just not sure how I could (easily) reproduce in the front end?

Has anyone been able to successfully develop anything that does this?

Comment: [Fabrik](http://fabrikar.com/) could come handy in some cases

Comment: @FFrewin thanks for the suggestion, I tried it once a few years back and found it to be quite complicated. Perhaps things have changed and I should give it another go.

Answer (score 3):

This information does exist in the frontend model, but for whatever reason, isn't actually displayed.

Copy `/components/com_users/views/profile/tmpl/default_core.php` to you template directory, so `/templates/yourtemplate/html/com_users/profile/default_core.php` and then in said template, you can dump the `data` object which will show all of the above, and more.

Dump the object using `<?php print_r($this->data);?>`

Then access the profile view using the profile URL: `index.php?option=com_users&view=profile`

Comment: Thanks for this. My template already has a file `/templates/yourtemplate/html/com_users/profile/default_core.php`. Visiting `index.php?option=com_users&view=profile` and `<?php print_r($this->data);?>` displays information for a *single* user. I was hoping to display a list of *all* users.

Comment: @jonboy I'd advise you research GDPR compliancy for this. To achieve your goal, however, you would need to look into 3rd party extensions or build your own. Community Builder gets my shout for this type of functionality, as I've used it previously for an alumni, but may be overkill for your project.

Answer (score 1):

I developed and mantain the Frontend User Manager extension that can show exactly that listing in the frontpage.

The current 0.0.6 stable release does exactly that and if you need user management in the front you can give a try to the 0.1.0alpha13 release.

Comment: Thanks for contributing Carlos.  Please consider introducing yourself and telling a bit of your Joomla story by editing your profile.